# LWP::Simple::get fails on a URL that works in the browser

Tags: json, perl, get

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use LWP::Simple;

my $cavirtex = get('https://www.cavirtex.com/api2/orderbook.json?currencypair=BTCCAD');
print $cavirtex;
```

When compiled, I get...

> Use of uninitialized value $cavirtex in print at cavirtex.pl line 9.

More info:
https://www.cavirtex.com/api_information#orderbook

Thanks.

EDIT/MORE INFO:
In my program, when I replace...

```
https://www.cavirtex.com/api2/orderbook.json?currencypair=BTCCAD
```

with...

```
https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/
```

it works just fine. Weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running the following command:

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'getprint "https://www.cavirtex.com/api2/orderbook.json?currencypair=BTCCAD"'
```

Yields the following result:

```
403 Forbidden <URL:https://www.cavirtex.com/api2/orderbook.json?currencypair=BTCCAD>
```

However, visiting the URL in a browser seems to work fine. This gives me the hunch that the user-agent is being checked or a cookie is required.

I decided to manually specify a known-good user-agent into my request. If this didn't work, I'd toy around with generating cookies.

Using the following code I got the desired results:

```
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36");
my $response = $ua->get('https://www.cavirtex.com/api2/orderbook.json?currencypair=BTCCAD');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
   die $response->status_line;
}
```

Hope that helps (TL;DR it looks like you needed a user agent set for this particular API call)

EDIT: the reason why it was working fine for the second URL you tried is because it's hitting a different API which doesn't seem to care about user-agent.

Answer (score 2):

@Dave Cooper answer is great. You can also change the LWP::Simple user agent this way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use LWP::Simple qw/$ua get/;

$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
my $cavirtex = get('https://www.cavirtex.com/api2/orderbook.json?currencypair=BTCCAD');
print $cavirtex;
```

**NOTE**: The `$ua` exported variable is an instance of `LWP::UserAgent`. `LWP::Simple` operations are delegated in this `$ua` object